# Would board and batten walls require drywall taping?

Tags: drywall, plywood, paneling

I have a room that has some wood paneling in it that we are going to have to replace, as it is old and has a missing section that is hidden by a cabinet we want to remove. I am considering doing either normal drywall or doing floor-to-ceiling board and batten walls for some extra style. For board and batten, I seemingly have two choices for the bottom layer: drywall, or paneling/plywood. I don't want MDF paneling, and HDF or wood paneling runs pretty expensive, as does plywood that's attractive enough. Therefore, even if I do choose to do board and batten I would like to stick with drywall.

My question would be if I do drywall WITH board and batten, would it still be necessary to tape the seams if I have 1 x 4 boards over them? Is still necessary for structural integrity?

Comment: ...board and batten is boards, not drywall or plywood, with battens (narrow boards) over the joints between boards. You appear to be doing something I might call drywall and battens, which is going to look entirely different than the same thing done with actual boards...

Comment: The idea would be something like what is shown here. I saw this same thing done in an Airbnb house I stayed in once, but I could not tell if the drywall had been pre-finished: https://thehappyhousie.porch.com/diy-floor-to-ceiling-board-batten/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessary. Generally speaking, taping is done entirely for aesthetic reasons (where a firewall isn't needed).

Comment: Plus for adding the fire wall that’s what I was thinking also.